# vue3: control property with a timed function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

First of all, I am a new vuejs developer and my purpose is to get acquainted with Vue, so, not going to use any external plugins or components.

I am writing a simple alert component, which looks like this:

```
<Alert :show="showAlert" />
```

I want the `show` property to return back to false after 2 seconds.  How can I do this from inside the component (i.e., not in the page where this component is used).  I tried this:

```
import { computed } from 'vue';
export default {
  props: ['show'],
  setup(props) {
      const shown = computed(() => {
          if (props.show) {
              setTimeout(() => {
                  console.log("hiding the alert...")
                  props.show = false
              }, 2000);
          }
          return props.show.value
      })
      return { shown }
  }
};
```

the compiler said:

```
14:15  error  Unexpected timed function in computed function  vue/no-async-in-computed-properties
16:19  error  Unexpected mutation of "show" prop              vue/no-mutating-props
```

My rational is that the delay of alert should be controlled by the alert component (which could be changed by a prop), but not forcing the caller to write some thing like:

```
function Alert(delay) {
    showAlert = true
    setTimeout(() => showAlert = false, delay)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 errors.

First vue/no-mutating-props, props are read only so you are not supposed to change it from within the component. It is still possible to change props from outside the component and pass down to it.

For this you should copy the value of props to your data()

```
data() {
  return {
    showAlert
  }
}
```

You should be able to update `showAlert` with no problem.

The second error vue/no-async-in-computed-properties, you cannot write async function inside computed(), so the alternative is to use `watch` instead.

Comment: watch vs. lifetime hook, which one is preferred?

Comment: lifetime hook seems not working, either onMounted() or onUpdated().  The problem is that it works only ones, but not repeatedly.

Comment: I haven't.  According to what I tried up-to-now, I estimate that will not succeed. It seems that the problem is the component cannot affect its parent, so that even if it successfully close the alert, the second time you press the button in parent component cannot trigger the alert anymore. @anurat-chapanond

Comment: @xrfang it seems you want to change parent's data, then you should call $emit('some event name', data) from the component then have the parent catch it. https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/emits-option.html#emits-option